# Encontrar caracteres duplicados y reemplazarlos con JavaScript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, replace, eliminar-duplicados

Estoy empezando con JavaScript y me he encontrado con un ejercicio en el que no encuentro el fallo.

El ejercicio consiste en encontrar los caracteres duplicados y reemplazarlos.

**Este es mi código:**

```js
let password = 'p3a3w%ut^%qb';
let separar = password.split('');
let filtrar = separar.filter((item, index) => {
  if (separar.indexOf(item) === index) {
    return item;
  } else {
    return separar.toString().replace(item, 'S');
  }
});

let newpassword = filtrar.join('');

console.log(newpassword);
console.log(newpassword.length);
```

No consigo que me reemplacen los caracteres repetidos por la `S`.

¿Alguien me puede explicar dónde tengo el fallo?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que estas usando el método `filter` para editar el array, pero de esta manera no se utiliza ese método, lo que hace ese método es quitar los elementos del array que no cumplan con la condición, solo se puede retorna `true` o `false`, lo que pasa en este caso es que estas retornando en ambos casos un carácter y eso lo toma como `true`, te recomiendo usar en lugar de `filter` el método `forEach`, para que recorras el array y puedas editar el elemento que este duplicado directamente, te quedaría asi:

```js
let password = 'p3a3w%ut^%qb';
let separar = password.split('');
separar.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (separar.indexOf(item) !== index) {
    return separar[index]='S';
  }
});

let newpassword = separar.join('');

console.log(newpassword);
console.log(newpassword.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explicación

Tomando en cuenta el siguiente texto de la pregunta:

> El ejercicio consiste en encontrar los caracteres duplicados y reemplazarlos

Debemos identificarlos y contarlos. Es decir, se podría construir un objeto en el que los caracteres se guardan como clave (`key`) y los valores como la cantidad de repeticiones del carácter.

Por lo tanto, creamos una función que haga eso para poder reutilizar el código.

> Lea todos los comentarios del código. Allí termino de explicar que hace cada línea.

```js
/**
 * Reemplazar caracteres repetidos.
 *
 * @param { string } text - Texto a reemplazar
 */
function replaceRepeated(text) {
  // Lanzamos un error
  if (typeof text !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Debe pasar como argumento un string");
  }

  // Creamos un objeto para guardar cada carácter como clave (`key`):
  const characters = {};

  // Iteramos cada carácter como si fuese un array para conocer cuántos
  // de ellos se encuentran repetidos y lo vamos contabilizando.
  for (const char of text) {
    characters[char] ??= 0;
    characters[char] += 1;
  }

  // Iteramos el objeto que tiene como clave (`key`) cada carácter:
  for (const char in characters) {
    const value = characters[char];

    // Si el caracter tiene un valor mayor que 1, significa que se encuentran
    // repetidos. Por lo tanto, procedemos a reemplazar caracteres repetidos:
    if (value > 1) {
      text = text.replaceAll(char, "S");
    }
  }

  // Devolvemos la cadena de caracteres reemplazadas.
  return text;
}

let password = "p3a3w%ut^%qb";
let newPassword = replaceRepeated(password);

console.log({
  password,
  newPassword
});
```